# PHP and MySQL Concurrency Issue

Tags: php, mysql, email, concurrency, pipe

I have an email piping system (PHP) that essentially inserts emails into a MySQL database when then are recieved. This works correctly for the most part.

The issue however comes when multiple recipients are used in the address field. In other words, the 'To:' header contains something like "a@example.com, b@example.com". This, understandebly is recieved by both a@example.com and b@example.com and so two (indentical) emails are inserted into the database. I just want one copy in the database.

My attempt to combat the problem initially was to check the existance of the email in the database before continuing with the pipe script. i.e.:

```
...
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM raw_emails WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $raw_email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if( $stmt->num_rows() > 0 ) die("Raw email already exists");
$stmt->close()

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO raw_emails VALUES(?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $raw_email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

...
```

This doesn't work, I presume since two instances of the pipe program run at (almost) the same time, so both instances finish the first block with 0 rows and proceed to insert the raw email twice.

I've also tried using transactions, to call a stored function, hoping one of the instances would wait for the other to commit before starting. The same problem occurs:

**MySQL**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `check_raw`(`raw_message_var` VARCHAR(25000)) RETURNS int(1)
BEGIN

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM raw_emails WHERE email = raw_message_var THEN
        RETURN 1;
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO raw_emails (email) VALUES (raw_message_var);
    END IF;

    RETURN 0;

END
```

**PHP**:

```
...
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT check_raw(?);");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $raw_email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($already_exists);
if( !$stmt->fetch() ) die($stmt->error);
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->commit();
if( $already_exists ) die("Raw email already exists");
...
```

Long story short: How can I have two or more instances only insert the email once into the database?

Comment: Are you actually comparing the email body? If that's the case, please don't. I hope your email would have a unique identifier (messageId) of some sort. Make that a primary key (or unique constraint) in your `raw_emails` table. That should solve your problem. If there's no unique messageId, create a hash (a really good one) out of the email message and make that hash column as a unique identifier in your raw_emails table.

Comment: What @TJ said.  However an answer to the generic problem is to use [table locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html), so only one thread can write to the table at a time (the others are forced to wait).

Comment: @TJ It isn't a problem of uniqueness, but concurrency. Both instances find no emails in the table (they don't exist yet) and therefore proceed to insert them.

Comment: Yes sir, I understand. What I am trying to point out over here is, with a Unique constraint in place, duplicate data cannot be inserted (But you should have a means of defining the uniqueness. I made some proposals). I don't really prefer to lock the table before each insert.

Comment: @TJ I apologise. The example I gave is a simplified version of the system I'm using.

I've managed to solve the problem now with a combination of a better message ID and locking tables. Thanks